# Is there any simple example of this kind of nonlinear and non-quadratic Lipschitz differentiable function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, non-convex-optimization

Suppose $f(x):R^n\rightarrow R$ satisfies the next 3 conditions:

1:$\nabla f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous.

2:$\nabla^2 f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous.

3:$\| \nabla f(x)\|\rightarrow\infty$ as $\|x\|\rightarrow\infty$.

Is there any simple example of nonlinear and non-quadratic function $f(x)$ which satisfies the last 3 conditions?

These conditions are given in some papers in optimization. But when I try to find such a example, I found it hard to construct a nonlinear and non-quadratic function satisfying all these conditions.

$\textbf{Motivation:}$ I am doing some researches in optimization. These conditions are useful in proving the convergence or error estimation. However, I need to do some numerical experiments to show the effectiveness of my algorithm, which requires some real examples.

Comment: What about $x\mapsto x^2$ vor $n=1$ or $x\mapsto \Vert x\Vert^2$ vor arbitrary $n$?

Comment: I am sorry. I know that quadratic function and linear function are two trivial examples. I treat quadratic function the same as linear function since its gradient is linear. Now I have edited it.

Comment: By the way, $cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$ satisfies the first two conditions.

Comment: Are polynomials in $\Vert x\Vert^2$ also trivial?

Comment: Clearly. Actually, all function like $x^TAx+b^Tx+c$ with $A$ positive definite satisfies this condition.

Comment: But certainly $x\mapsto \exp(\Vert x\Vert^2)$ should serve as a non-trivial example.

Comment: The derivative of this function is not Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one answer this question, I post my own thought here. To the best of my knowledge, there are two examples:

1:$\log(1+\exp(Ax+b))$. Here we use the notation $\exp(x):=\exp(x_1)+..\exp(x_n)$ for vector $x\in R^n$.

2:$x^TAx+cos(Bx)$, Here $A$ is a positive definite matrix, and the notation $cos(x):=cos(x_1)+...+cos(x_n)$ for $x\in R^n$.